# measure frequency and duty cycle using input capture in avr

Tags: timer, avr, atmega

I am having a hard time getting around the concept of input capture and how to write a simple code that would measure the PWM of a tachometer for example through input capture and timers in AVR....

Comment: Its not "a code", just "code". Code is a mass noun and cannot combine with an indefinite article.

Answer (score 2):

Input capture is simply giving a timestamp to an external event. For PWM these events are rising edge and falling edge.
Once enabled, the timer of ATMEGA starts incrementing with clock. Whenever an event occurs, it copies the timer value at that moment to an input capture register and generates an interrupt. In interrupt service routine your program is supposed to read this register and interpret the values to calculate duty cycle or whatever.
In this ISR you also have to reconfigure your timer register to look for alternate edge as PWM has alternating edges.
I am giving a rough register configuration for ATMEGA16L, you can find full details in data sheet.

TCCR1B - bit6 set for rising, reset for falling. Have to toggle in ISR

TCCR1B - bit 0,1,2 used to set clock pre-scaler

TIMSK  - bit5 enable input capture interrupt

TIMSK  - bit0 timer overflow interrupt enable needed for calculations